# Online exchange bitcoin balance to hardware wallet

Tags: wallet, coinbase.com, trezor

For better security, how would I move bitcoin from my Coinbase Wallet and Vault to a hardware wallet like Trezor?

Answer (score 3):

Generate an address on the hardware wallet.  Then log in to your web wallet account and send all your coins to that address.  That's all.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Jaxx wallet. It is available on most platforms and mobile.

https://jaxx.io/

Simply open the app, it will generate a new wallet, and you can use your coinbase wallet to send bitcoins to the new address.

Coinbase is not a good place to keep bitcoins.