# How to buy bitcoin to my local harddrive?

Tags: wallet

There are stories about people searchung dumps for their thrown away harddrives with bictoins with brazillions of money. I want to get such harddrive too :)

Is it possible nowadays? I.e. buy bitcois directly to my wallet, without any third party accounts?

I registered on `CoinMarketCap` and `coinbase` and looks like first site doesn't allow to buy bitcoins and another is maintaining it's own accounts with their security and 3rd party auth. But I don't want their accounts, I want my on my local selfcontained harddrive.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to:

- Look into hosting your own [bitcoin node](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18736/what-is-a-bitcoin-node).
- Try using P2P non-custodial non-kyc exchange, you can find the [list here](https://kycnot.me/).
- You may want not to store your wallet on a hard drive. The suggested
  solution is to own a [hardware wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48901/online-exchange-bitcoin-balance-to-hardware-wallet)